# Looping through continous record in MSAccess

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, vba

**Context:**
I made a Vacation tracking module in my database. The employees can request advanced hours take off in a current year period and it will be deducted from their next years period.

**The Case:**
I am trying to make a continuous loop through the recordset of employees to see if they have been awarded advanced hours and if yes add it to the vacation hours they have.

**The Problem:**
I have the logic down but I can't get it to loop through each employee on my continuous form.

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
    While Not .EOF
        adv = DLookup("advhours", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
        vac = DLookup("vhrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
        adate = DLookup("advdate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
        andatestart = DLookup("anndate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
        andateend = DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple([andatestart]), [andatestart])
        anddateend = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, andateend)
        morehours = DLookup("totalvachrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")

        sum = adv + vac


        If adv > 0 And adate > DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple([andatestart]), [andatestart]) And adate < anddateend And morehours = 0 Then
            morehours = 1

            ' sets the flag to 1 if true.
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & "SET dbo_employees.totalvachrs='" & morehours & "' " & "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"

            'increment vacation hours
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & "SET dbo_employees.vhrs='" & sum & "' " & "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"

        End If

        'after Vac hours have been updated..

        If morehours = 1 And adate < andateend Then
            ' puts vacation hours back down to where they were.
            vac = vac - adv
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                                "SET dbo_employees.vhrs='" & _
                                vac & "' " & _
                                "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"
            adv = 0
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                                "SET dbo_employees.advhours='" & _
                                adv & "' " & _
                                "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"
             morehours = 0
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                                "SET dbo_employees.totalvachrs='" & _
                                morehours & "' " & _
                                "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"

       End If
      Debug.Print txtempid ' CTRL G to see

      If Not .EOF Then .MoveNext
    Wend
End With
MsgBox "after loop: " & txtempid
```

I have also tried this as well, but i get drop changes dialogue in access

```
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

rs.MoveFirst


Do While Not rs.EOF
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    adv = DLookup("advhours", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
    vac = DLookup("vhrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
    adate = DLookup("advdate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
    andatestart = DLookup("anndate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")
    andateend = DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple([andatestart]), [andatestart])
    anddateend = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, andateend)
    morehours = DLookup("totalvachrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = txtempid")

    sum = adv + vac


    If adv > 0 And adate > DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple([andatestart]), [andatestart]) And adate < anddateend And morehours = 0 Then
        morehours = 1

        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & "SET dbo_employees.totalvachrs='" & morehours & "' " & "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"

        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & "SET dbo_employees.vhrs='" & sum & "' " & "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"      

    End If

    If morehours = 1 And adate < andateend Then
        vac = vac - adv
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                            "SET dbo_employees.vhrs='" & _
                            vac & "' " & _
                            "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"
        adv = 0
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                            "SET dbo_employees.advhours='" & _
                            adv & "' " & _
                            "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"
        morehours = 0
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE dbo_employees " & _
                            "SET dbo_employees.totalvachrs='" & _
                            morehours & "' " & _
                            "WHERE dbo_employees.empid=" & txtempid & ";"

    End If

    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you try a `Do While Loop`?

Comment: Yes, i just edited my post to show my loop for a Do While but still no luck

Comment: show the query..also r u sure the recordset contain the rows?

Comment: Right... step through the code in debug mode and see if it is indicating it is EOF too soon.  If that's the case, your recordSet is not what you are expecting-- Which means your query is incorrect

Comment: The record set is correct, also with the first example the EOF is too soon but in the second example it goes through all 30 records but then has a drop change dialogue at the end of it. So my thinking was it is a loop problem i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Dotydot so your second example is working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotyDot,

I think that your problem is a basic misunderstanding of how recordsets and forms (and continuous forms) work.

Regardless of whether the form is a regular form (one record displayed at a time) or a continuous form (multiple records displayed at a time), the ability and limitations in referencing values (fields) on the form and/or use the recordset does not change.

You can't "loop" through a continuous form in code and reference the controls on the form (txtempid) and get the value from each record, as you are trying to do.

Anytime you reference a control on a form, you will only get the value for that control associated with the current record.

Looping through a recordset, even if you instantiate the recordset from the form recordsetclone, will NOT change the current record pointer on the form.

Your second code example is closest to something that will work, but still needs some work.  First, when working with a recordset in code, you will most likely NOT reference the form controls, you will reference the field values directly from the recordset.  I don't know your table structure, but here is an example that should get you on the right track.

I assume that this code will run on a button click, or some other event where you are wanting to evaluate all employees.

```
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
Do While Not rst.EOF
  adv = DLookup("advhours", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = " & rst("empid"))
  vac = DLookup("vhrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = " & rst("empid"))
  adate = DLookup("advdate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = " & rst("empid"))
  andatestart = DLookup("anndate", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = " & rst("empid"))
  andateend = DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple(rst("andatestart")), rst("andatestart"))
  anddateend = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, rst("andateend"))
  morehours = DLookup("totalvachrs", "dbo_employees", "[empid] = " & rst("empid"))

  sum = adv + vac

  If adv > 0 And adate > DateAdd("yyyy", AgeSimple(rst("andatestart")), rst("andatestart")) And adate < anddateend And morehours = 0 Then      
    morehours = 1
    rst.Edit
    rst("totalvachrs") = morehours
    rst("vhrs") = sum
    rst.Update
  End If

  If morehours = 1 And adate < andateend Then
    vac = vac - adv
    rst.Edit
    rst("vhrs") = vac
    adv = 0
    rst("advhours") = adv
    morehours = 0
    rst("totalvachrs") = morehours
    rst.Update
  End If

  rst.MoveNext
Loop
Set rst = Nothing
'Refresh the screen
Me.Requery
```

You don't need to use DoCmd.RunSQL, you can edit the data directly in the Recordset via code.

Please note that in your example code, anyplace where you appeared to be referencing a control on the form

> [andatestart]

I changed it to reference that field name in the recordset

> rst("andatestart")

This code will loop through every record on your form and perform the calculations and updates you were doing.

> FYI, in your original code, by setting the form bookmark (Me.Bookmark)
>   to the recordset Bookmark, you were forcing the form to move the
>   current record pointer through each record, but that is really not the
>   best way to accomplish what you are trying to do, IMO

I hope this helps.